# Opennms initialization fails

Tags: opennms

Opennms initialization fails and when I run sudo service opennms start following error comes:

```
Starting Open Network Management System: opennmserror invoking "check" operation: Data source 'opennms' failed.
OpenNMS was unable to connect to the 'opennms' database configured in opennms-datasources.xml.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this the first start of new installation? If yes, what is the operating system version, what is the version of OpenNMS Horizon you have installed? The error message stated, OpenNMS is not able to connect to the database which is configured in the opennms-datasources.xml. Have you checked the configuration?

Comment: No this is not the first installation and  operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: And yes I have checked the configuration according to the official documentation of opennms: pg_gba.conf and postgres.conf.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get says “permission denied for relation ...” You have two options, a) set a root password for Postgres root user and configure it in the opennms-data sources.xml and verify you use md5 in pg_hba.conf, b) make a less secure configuration setting 127.0.0.1 to trust in pg_hba.conf. This allow everyone to connect to Postgres from local host without authentication. I would recommend a) which is described in our install guide in the link above.

Comment: Yeah, now it works but , still the problem when i try somme configuration changes for datacollection , I have to restart opennms after which it never starts

Answer (score 0):

The error message: "OpenNMS was unable to connect to the 'opennms'" indicates a very low level problem.

- Do you have PostgreSQL running on the same server OpenNMS is running?
- Is PostgreSQL listening on port 5432: you can use `ss -l sport = :5432`?
- Can you connect to the PostgreSQL database with `psql` using the same credentials as you have configured in the `opennms-datasources.xml`?
- What happens if you run the `${OPENNMS_HOME}/bin/install -dis` command?

Comment: Yes , Postgres is running in same server as opennms.

Comment: And yes, Postgres is listening on the port 5432, And i can connect to psql using opennms user and by running the last command u mentioned it starts but after every restart the opennms server crashes saying dpkg error and Java exceptions regarding the peer connection failure with opennms user

Comment: What is the dpkg error? It seems to me this is not related to the "Java exception" which has problems to connect to your PostgreSQL database.

In the opennms-datasources.xml are two credentials, one with the postgres root user to modify database schemas and a second one to use just the opennms database. Can you verify if you have initialised the PostgreSQL database accordingly as described in "Step 2" in our installation guide: http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/branches/develop/guide-install/guide-install.html#_installing_on_debian

Comment: Following errors comes when I execute ${OPENNMS_HOME}/bin/install -dis

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: org.opennms.core.schema.MigrationException: unable to migrate the database
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL SELECT LOCKED FROM databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1: ERROR: permission denied for relation databasechangeloglock\
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL SELECT LOCKED FROM databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1: ERROR: permission denied for relation databasechangeloglock

Comment: Everytime I try to restart opennms it never starts ans shows these errors